# indicator-messages binary location

Tags: 13.04, binary, location

Where is the `indicator-messages` binary located or from which package is the binary for the Indicator where Evolution and Empathy messages are shown?

```
dpkg -L indicator-messages | grep bin
```

shows me nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It is not in the regular `bin` directory as it is not an application which should be run directly by the user. It is `/usr/lib/indicator-messages/indicator-messages-service` instead, as it is launched programmatically by other means.

If you simply want to not have it ever shown, you can simply do `sudo apt-get remove --purge indicator-messages` and kill the existing process, or log out and back in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to remove it. I want to start it in a GNOME-Shell. I tried the Elementary OS and I that there is the messaging menu. As far as I know, there deskop environment is a 'GNOME-Shell fork'.

Comment: `~$ /usr/lib/indicator-messages/indicator-messages
bash: /usr/lib/indicator-messages/indicator-messages: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden` not found

Comment: Sorry, had the filename slightly wrong. Updated the answer. But I don't think gnome-shell supports indicators (running the indicator doesn't put an icon in the shell here).

Comment: If you use [appindicator-support](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/) you can use indicators in the panel, but I don't know if it works for the messaging menu. I try it tomorrow.